# Inverse Laplace transform of $\frac{1}{s\sinh{c\sqrt{s}}}$

Tags: calculus, laplace-transform, residue-calculus

I have some questions.

I have to take the inverse Laplace transform of the given function below by residue theorem:

$\frac{1}{s\sinh{c\sqrt{s}}}$

where s is Laplacian variable and c is a real constant. Actually it has a very crowded numerator which I do not need to define. So far I know that it has a simple pole at s = zero and infinitely many poles at c√s = nπi

Questions:

1- What is the order of the poles at nπi? Is it 1/2?

2- At zero, what is the order? (Because to residue at zero, s also contributes)

3- What is the way of solving this question at nπi by residue theorem (without defining sinh function as exponential function)?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. You can format maths with [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: By the very definition of *pole*, a pole cannot have order $\frac{1}{2}$ or  $\frac{3}{2}$. Before applying the residue theorem, you have to perform some manipulation granting you to deal with an actual meromorphic function.

Answer (score 0):

By the residue theorem we have (assuming $c,s>0$)
$$ \frac{\pi}{\sin(\pi z)}=\frac{1}{z}+\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{2z(-1)^n}{z^2-n^2} \tag{1}$$
$$ \frac{1}{\sinh(z)}=\frac{1}{z}+\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{2z(-1)^n}{z^2+\pi^2 n^2} \tag{2}$$
$$ \frac{1}{\sinh(cz)}=\frac{1}{cz}+\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{2cz(-1)^n}{c^2z^2+\pi^2 n^2} \tag{3}$$
$$ \frac{1}{\sinh(c\sqrt{s})}=\frac{1}{c\sqrt{s}}+\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{2c\sqrt{s}(-1)^n}{c^2 s+\pi^2 n^2} \tag{4}$$
$$ \frac{1}{\sqrt{s}\sinh(c\sqrt{s})}=\frac{1}{c s}+\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{2c(-1)^n}{c^2 s+\pi^2 n^2} \tag{5}$$

$$\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{s}\sinh(c\sqrt{s})}\right)=\frac{1}{c }+\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{2}{c}(-1)^n \exp\left(-\frac{n^2 \pi^2 x}{c^2}\right) =\color{blue}{\tfrac{1}{c}\,\vartheta_4\left(0;e^{-\pi^2 x/c^2}\right)}\tag{6}$$
so the answer in this case is given by a [Jacobi Theta function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/JacobiThetaFunctions.html). Similarly,
$$\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left( \frac{1}{s\sinh(c\sqrt{s})}\right)=\frac{2\sqrt{x}}{c\sqrt{\pi}}+\frac{4}{\pi^{3/2}}\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^n}{n}\,F\left(\frac{\pi n \sqrt{x}}{c}\right)\tag{7} $$
where $F$ is [Dawson function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dawson_function). The last series is related with an integral involving the $\vartheta_4$ function.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding Jack D'Aurizio's comment and a typo had seen in the first post, I think you want to find inverse Laplace transform of $f(s)=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{s}\sinh c\sqrt{s}}$. Then from
$$\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{s}\sinh c\sqrt{s}}=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{s}\left((c\sqrt{s})+\dfrac{(c\sqrt{s})^3}{3!}+\dfrac{(c\sqrt{s})^5}{5!}+\cdots\right)}=\dfrac{1}{cs\left(1+\dfrac{c^2s}{3!}+\dfrac{c^4s^2}{5!}+\cdots\right)}$$
shows this function has a simple pole in $s=0$, also for other poles we have $\sinh c\sqrt{s}=0$ which determines poles $s_k=-\dfrac{k^2\pi^2}{c^2}$. So the residues of $e^{st}f(s)$ at these poles are
\begin{align}
\lim_{s\to0}(s-0)\dfrac{e^{st}}{\sqrt{s}\sinh c\sqrt{s}} 
&= \dfrac{e^{0}}{c.1} \\
&= \dfrac{1}{c} \\
\lim_{s\to s_k}(s-s_k)\dfrac{e^{st}}{\sqrt{s}\sinh c\sqrt{s}} 
&= \lim_{s\to s_k}e^{st}\dfrac{1+ts+t\dfrac{k^2\pi^2}{c^2}}{\dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{s}}\left(\sinh c\sqrt{s}+c\sqrt{s}\cosh c\sqrt{s}\right) } \hspace{2cm}\text{With L'Hopital}\\
&= e^{s_kt}\dfrac{2}{c}(-1)^k\\
&= \dfrac{2(-1)^k}{c}e^{-\dfrac{k^2\pi^2}{c^2}t}
\end{align}
hence
$${\cal L}^{-1}\left(\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{s}\sinh c\sqrt{s}}\right)=\color{blue}{\dfrac{1}{c}+\dfrac{2}{c}\sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^ke^{-\dfrac{k^2\pi^2}{c^2}t}}$$

Comment: Thanks @MyGlasses for the great answer! But I could not understand where the "cosh" term in the denominator comes. I have looked up all the advanced calculus books in hand, but I could not find it.

Comment: Use l'Hopital and derivate!

Comment: But it seems that you have applied l'hopital before you cancelled out the s terms in the numerator and the denominator. They cancel each other first and then you do not need to apply l'hopital indeed. Also for the second pole (the one for sinh) the same situation happens. Why do I need l'hopital? There is no 0/0 or inf/inf uncertainty for both cases. Am I wrong?

Comment: How you cancel them? $s-s_k$ and $\sqrt{s}$. show me please!